# Angular 2/4 Service Provider does not compile if a function

Tags: angular, angular2-services, service-provider

I have a generic REST service which i want to call using a Service Provider so that I can pass in the URL.
I want to do this so that the service can be reusable  across multiple projects (each using a different REST API) or even within different components of the same project.

I have the following as my Service Provider:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { ODataService } from './odata.service';

export function ODataServiceProvider(url: string) {
    return {
        provide: ODataService, 
        useFactory: (http: any) => {
            return new ODataService(url, http);
        },
        deps: [Http]
    }
}
```

I should now in theory be able to use this Service Provider in individual components or at the app.module level and pass through the url; I have done it in the app.module.ts like so:

```
providers: [ 
      SafeUrlPipe,
      ODataServiceProvider("http://services.odata.org/V3/(S(pq1lpmgz0kuok05ubqtx1c2g))/OData/OData.svc/") 
  ],
```

This now will through an error when i serve the project (or build):

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to  an exported function (position 8:21 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving symbol ODataServiceProvider in
>   C:/dev/SVN/Products/PredictiveAnalytics/Trunk/Glencor
>   eAnalyticsPortal/GlencoreAnalyticsPortal.Webclient/src/app/shared/services/odata/odata.serviceProvider.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in C:/dev/SVN/Products/P
>   redictiveAnalytics/Trunk/GlencoreAnalyticsPortal/GlencoreAnalyticsPortal.Webclient/src/app/app.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in C:/dev/SVN/Products/Pr
>   edictiveAnalytics/Trunk/GlencoreAnalyticsPortal/GlencoreAnalyticsPortal.Webclient/src/app/app.module.ts

However if i save any file while the project is served and being watched it will now not throw an error and everything will work as expected.
Any clue how to fix this issue? Is this an Angular issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it work as expected using **Injection Token** and changing the **Service Provider** a bit:

The new Service Provider is as such:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ODataService } from './odata.service';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const URL = new InjectionToken<string>('url');

export function ODataServiceProvider(url: string, http: Http) {
    return new ODataService(url, http);
}
```

This now has a simple string called URL that can be injected, and the Provider now has 2 dependencies/parameters that it requires.
We will inject both these in, this can be done in any component as follows (unnecessary code has been omitted):

```
import { ODataServiceProvider, URL } from './shared/services/odata/odata.serviceProvider';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ODataService } from './shared/services/odata/odata.service';


providers: [ 
    {
        provide: URL,
        useValue: 'http://services.odata.org/V3/(S(pq1lpmgz0kuok05ubqtx1c2g))/OData/OData.svc/'
    },
    {
        provide: ODataService,
        useFactory: ODataServiceProvider,
        deps: [URL, Http]
    }
  ]
```

note the URL is now assigned as a provider and then used in deps, which will allow it to be injected to the Service Provider.

Not sure if this is the best way to do things but it seems to work.

To build on this further you could actually have the URL string be a interface if the Service Provider needs a set of config such as shown in the Angular API: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injection-token

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that happens, but I got a similar problem and resolved like the following.

Export a function that returns your service build outside your ngmodule and then call it inside your providers with {provide:, useFactory:}

```
export function myDataService() {  
  return ODataServiceProvider("http://services.odata.org/V3/(S(pq1lpmgz0kuok05ubqtx1c2g))/OData/OData.svc/");
}
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ 
      SafeUrlPipe,
      {
        provide: MyProvider,
        useFactory: myDataService
      }
  ]
})
```

It must be something like this...

Comment: compiles now, but seems like its providing the actual function now.

Comment: so i cannot access the actual service like before.